# Kubespawner & Jupyterhub: how to assign environment variable dynamically

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I wonder how to set environment variable dynamically in user's pod which is launched by kubespawner.

I have some predefined profilees and each one has different environment variables.

```yaml
singleuser:
  profileList:
    - display_name: "Test"
      kubespawner_override:
        environment:
          MY_TEST: "$(JUPYTERHUB_USER)"
          DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: "$(dbus-launch --sh-syntax | awk -F\' 'NR==1{print $2}')"
```

I intended to execute `dbus-launch --sh-syntax | awk -F\' 'NR==1{print $2}'`

and then, assign its output to `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` variable.

However, `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` was literally assigned with `dbus-launch --sh-syntax | awk -F\' 'NR==1{print $2}'` .

---

As an another option, I tried to add hub.extraConfig as well.
(referenced [here](https://github.com/jupyterhub/kubespawner/issues/306#issuecomment-789718547))

It just failed to launch pod....

```yaml
hub:
  extraConfig:
    dbus_set_config: |
        async def pre_spawn_hook(spawner):
            output = os.popen("dbus-launch --sh-syntax").read().split('\n')
            spawner.environment.update({
                "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS": output[0].split("'")[1]
                })

        c.KubeSpawner.pre_spawn_hook = pre_spawn_hook
```

How can I add dynamically generated variable into user's notebook pod as environment variable?